# order categories through wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

using `query_posts`

```
<?php query_posts("&cat=775,777,779&posts_per_page=12&orderby=date");?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

i'm trying to run through 3 categories and post like so...

cat1post1, cat2post1, cat3post1, cat1post2, cat2post2, cat3post2, etc... and order by date... can this be accomplished with only 1 loop?

Comment: Can you pls tell us what's not working in above code of yours?

Comment: @anubhava it spits them out strictly ordered by date.. so it could be like cat1post1, cat1post2, cat3post1, cat2post1, cat2post2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For this type of customized post ordering you can install a Wordpress plugin called: [aStickyPostOrderER](http://pixelplexus.co.za/blog/2007/11/20/plugin-to-change-wordpress-post-order/) It lets you customize the order of appearance of posts per category, per tag **or over-all** in a WordPress (versions 2.3+) blog.